# Why does my xdotool key command not work?

Tags: command-line, 15.04, xdotool

I'm trying to run this command:

```
xdotool key ctrl+super+d
```

It is supposed to toggle-show desktop, but it won't work. When I press the keys myself it works though.

Comment: From 12.04+ don't you have that feature with Ctrl+Super+D?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct command is:

```
xdotool key Control_L+Super_L+d
```

To find the correct key- mentions, use `xev`: In a terminal window, run the command `xev` + <kbd>Return</kbd>, then type the key you'd like to use in the `xdotool` command. The output will be like:

```
KeyPress event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4c00001,
    root 0x260, subw 0x0, time 64862215, (-177,259), root:(1325,592),
    state 0x10, keycode 133 (keysym 0xffeb, Super_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

where the information you are looking for is in the section:

```
(keysym 0xffeb, Super_L)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `keysym` -value:

```
xdotool key Control_L+0xffeb+d
```

or the key code:

```
xdotool key Control_L+133+d
```

#### Additional information

As mentioned by @DKBose:
on `14.04`, the command, used by OP *should* work, as mentioned in `man xdotool` on `14.04.3`:

*Generally, any valid X Keysym string will work. Multiple keys are separated by '+'. Aliases exist for "alt", "ctrl", "shift", "super", and "meta" which all map to Foo_L, such as Alt_L and Control_L .*

However, OP mentions the tag `15.04`, and on `15.04`, the passage is missing in `man xdotool`, and the aliasses do not work any more. The values, found in the output of `xev` should be used.

Comment: @DKBose Good point, however, on 15.04 the passage is missing in `man xdotool`, and it is not working either. I will add it to the answer.

Comment: @DKBose that is odd. All I can say is aliasses do work on 14.04 here, but not on 15.04. The output of `xev` works in all cases however.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to sound silly, but verify you're on X11 and not Wayland:

```
echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
```

If it outputs `wayland` it won't work (**x**dotool)